# ruby file execute lock to avoid multiple process for the same script

Tags: ruby

In my ruby script I have put below code to make sure the same script should not be executed again parallel when another process is already running.

```
if $0 == __FILE__
  if File.new(__FILE__).flock(File::LOCK_EX | File::LOCK_NB)
    if RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'].include? 'linux'
      linux_main
    elsif RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'].include? 'mingw'
      windows_main
    elsif RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'].include? 'solaris'
      solaris_main
    end
  end
end

__END__
```

But its not working as expected on Windows. I have initiated one process and when I run initiate another process on another powershell session its still running instead of coming out.

Any suggestion pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's `File` class is mostly a thin layer on top of POSIX. As a result, several methods either don't work or behave differently on non-POSIX platforms. This is explicitly acknowledged in the documentation, e.g. [the method you are using says](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-i-flock):

> Not available on all platforms.

It is also implementation-dependent. E.g. JRuby went through the trouble to develop a full POSIX compatibility layer for Java, and as a result, on Windows, JRuby actually is more conforming with Ruby than "Ruby" (i.e. YARV) is!

Long story short: `File#flock` is just a thin layer on top of POSIX's `flock` function, and that function simply doesn't exist on Windows. Note that Windows *does* support file locking using the `LockFile` Windows API function. However, it doesn't support POSIX file locking. (Except maybe in a POSIX emulation environment such as Mirosoft Services for Unix, MSYS, or Cygwin.)